# DB design: domain object is a fixed column, fixed row table, how to design a DB table for it?

Tags: database, database-design

designing my current app I've run into a problem: the user provided the following requirement:

For each enterprise (let's say there's an enterprise table, with enterprise_id as key), there is a fixed dataset, structured more or less like this:

```
             | Income | Declared | Expenses | Normalized | Whatever | etc
-------------+--------+----------+----------+------------+----------+-...
Short term   |
Medium term  |
Long term    |
Unspecified  |
Unknown      |
```

The key point is that (conceptually) the columns are fixed and the rows are fixed. And by fixed, I mean it's a written law in my country! So it's not gonna change in the short term.

My doubt is: each instance of the "user" table (with its fixed M columns and N rows) looks like a DB row to me (there's a 1:1 correspondence with enterprise_id, all the data is going to get saved/retrieved as a single block each time, etc). On the other hand, this is a lot of columns (MxN may be a hundred in my real app), and, frankly, it's ugly to look at, so I'm uneasy about it.

So, should I create a table for this user data, with (MxN) columns (plus one for the enterprise_id foreign key), or should I go along the lines of creating two tables, one with the possible "user" rows ("short term", etc), and another with only the columns ("income", etc), being each row in this case (enterprise_id, possible_rows_id, income, declared_income, etc).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ". . . along the lines of creating two tables" What columns would you join those two tables on?

Comment: If lawmakers dictate your database design, you're out of luck. If you can get away with it, adhere to the intent of the law without mimicking its details. In any reasonable world, if you can recreate the format required by law on the screen or in an extract, you're within the intent of the law.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are all some kind of currency, my first thought was that you probably needed a table like this:

```
term          category    term_category_value
--            --          --
Short term    Income      <some currency amount>
Short term    Declared    <some currency amount>
...
Short term    Whatever    <some currency amount>
Middle term   Income      <some currency amount>
Middle term   Declared    <some currency amount>
...
```

Depending on your dbms, making this kind of data look like a spreadsheet might be fairly easy or mildly hard. But you only have to build one view to do that. SQL Server has PIVOT, for example. Some other platforms call it CROSSTAB.

Comment: Yep, that's another possiblity: each cell in the "user" table is a row in a DB table. It's the second option I considered but using two dimensions instead of one. Unfortunately, not all columns are currency and, anyway, I think I don't like it either, as I feel this solution adds degrees of freedom where there's not needed of it (all fields are mandatory, but this design cannot enforce it). Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you can enforce fairly arbitrary CHECK constraints if your dbms allows user-defined functions in CHECK constraints. But the different data types are pretty much a show-stopper for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are 1::1 with Enterprise, they should be in Enterprise.  But at somepoint you will run into row-length maximum.

Therefore use a second table with MxN columns plus EnterpriseId as both PK and FK.